# JavaScript DomEvent Passing multiple checkbox values

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with multiple checkbox values. A user may select one or more than one options

html code

```
    <div id="container">
        <h1 id="title">RGB Color</h1>
        <div id="color">#000</div>
        <div id="checkColor">
            <!--red-->
            <input type="checkbox" id="red">Red
            <!--green-->
            <input type="checkbox" id="green">Green
            <!--blue-->
            <input type="checkbox" id="blue">Blue
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript code

```
//red box
function red_box(event) {
    var redbox = document.getElementById("red")
    //red
    if (redbox.checked) {
        console.log('red')
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#f00";
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#f00"
        document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#f00";
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#f00";
    }
    else {
        console.log('red e')
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#000";
    }
}

//green box
function green_box(event) {
    var greenbox = document.getElementById("green")
    //green
    if (greenbox.checked) {
        console.log('gree')
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#090";
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#090"
        document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#090";
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#090";
    }
    else {
        console.log('gree e')
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#000";
    }
}

//blue box
function blue_box(event) {
    var bluebox = document.getElementById("blue")
    //blue
    if (bluebox.checked) {
        console.log('blue')
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#00f";
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#00f"
        document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#00f";
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#00f";
    }
    else {
        console.log('blue e')
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#000";
    }
}

//0ff blue green
function off() {
    
    var bluebox = document.getElementById("blue")
    var greenbox = document.getElementById("green")
    if ((bluebox.checked) && (greenbox.checked)) {
        console.log('off')
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#0ff";
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#0ff"
        document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#0ff";
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#0ff";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#000";
    }
}

//red green = ff0
function ffo() {
    var redbox = document.getElementById("red")
    var greenbox = document.getElementById("green")
    if ((redbox.checked) && (greenbox.checked)) {
        console.log('ffo')
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#ff0";
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#ff0"
        document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#ff0";
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#ff0";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#000";
    }
}

//red blue = f0f
function fof() {
    var redbox = document.getElementById("red")
    var bluebox = document.getElementById("blue")
    if ((redbox.checked) && (bluebox.checked)) {
        console.log('fof')
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#f0f";
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#f0f"
        document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#f0f";
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#f0f";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#000";
    }
}

//all
function allbox(event) {
    var redbox = document.getElementById("red")
    var bluebox = document.getElementById("blue")
    var greenbox = document.getElementById("green")
    if ((redbox.checked) && (bluebox.checked) && (greenbox.checked)) {
        console.log('all')
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#fff";
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#fff";
        document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#000";
    }
};


//funtion start
document.getElementById('red').onclick = red_box;
document.getElementById('green').onclick = green_box;
document.getElementById('blue').onclick = blue_box;

// document.getElementById("checkColor").onclick = ffo;
// document.getElementById("checkColor").onclick = off;
// document.getElementById("checkColor").onclick = fof;
```

I want to change the color when two or more checkboxes are selected.
Ex :When you check red & blue, you want to change the color to #f0f.
Is it possible to run javascript without editing html?
I'm spending a lot of time with this issue. Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a lot of problem in your code first you reapeat the same line of code a lot of time you have in stead to assign the variable you will use it a lot of time in variable instead of write all of this every time  `document.getElementById("red");` assing this in variable like this `var redbox = document.getElementById("red");` its will be better and if you need to modify anything in your project you don't need to modify it tens of times. second you should add event click to call the function that you have create,

```
redbox.addEventListener("click", Which_color ) 
bluebox.addEventListener("click", Which_color ) 
greenbox.addEventListener("click", Which_color )
```

you didn't call the function so nothing happen in your code, i add also whichColor function that will handle how to choose between the color and detect which color is active,

```
function Which_color(){
  if(redbox.checked && greenbox.checked && bluebox.checked){
    allbox();
  }
  else if( redbox.checked && greenbox.checked){ffo();}
   else if( redbox.checked && bluebox.checked){fof();}
   else if( greenbox.checked  && bluebox.checked){off();}
   else if (redbox.checked){red_box()}
   else if (bluebox.checked){blue_box()}
   else if (greenbox.checked){green_box()}
   else{nobox()}
}
```

i also add function nobox(); to detect if no box is checked. you should stop reapeat your self you type this code in 5 function

```
  document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#000";
                document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#fff";
                document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#000";
                document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = 

"#000";
```

instead you have to create function that handle unchecked boxes instead of repeat the same code 5 time

hope its helpful.

```js
var redbox = document.getElementById("red");
var greenbox = document.getElementById("green");
var bluebox = document.getElementById("blue");



function Which_color(){
  if(redbox.checked && greenbox.checked && bluebox.checked){
    allbox();
  }
  else if( redbox.checked && greenbox.checked){ffo();}
   else if( redbox.checked && bluebox.checked){fof();}
   else if( greenbox.checked  && bluebox.checked){off();}
   else if (redbox.checked){red_box()}
   else if (bluebox.checked){blue_box()}
   else if (greenbox.checked){green_box()}
   else{nobox()}
}
 

function red_box() {
        console.log('red')
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#f00";
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#f00"
        document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#fff";
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#f00";
}

//green box
function green_box(event) {
    //green
        console.log('gree')
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#090";
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#090"
        document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#090";
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#090";
}

//blue box
function blue_box(event) {
        console.log('blue')
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#00f";
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#00f"
        document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#00f";
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#00f";
}

//0ff blue green
function off() {

        console.log('off')
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#0ff";
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#0ff"
        document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#0ff";
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#0ff";
    
}

//red green = ff0
function ffo() {
        console.log('ffo')
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#ff0";
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#ff0"
        document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#ff0";
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#ff0";
}

//red blue = f0f
function fof() {
        console.log('fof')
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#f0f";
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#f0f"
        document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#f0f";
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#f0f";
}

//all
function allbox(event) {
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#fff";
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#fff";
        document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
};

function nobox(){
     document.getElementById("title").style.color = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").style.color = "#fff";
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = "#000";
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#000";
}

redbox.addEventListener("click", Which_color ) 
bluebox.addEventListener("click", Which_color ) 
greenbox.addEventListener("click", Which_color )
```

```html
 <div id="container">
        <h1 id="title">RGB Color</h1>
        <div id="color">#000</div>
        <div id="checkColor">
            <!--red-->
            <input type="checkbox" id="red">Red
            <!--green-->
            <input type="checkbox" id="green">Green
            <!--blue-->
            <input type="checkbox" id="blue">Blue
        </div>
    </div>
```